# Simulating HCPL-3700 using LTSpice

Tags: ac, dc, opto-isolator, voltage-measurement, voltage-detector

I am trying to simulate HCPL-3700 using the LTSpice model provided by [Broadcom](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optocouplers/industrial-plastic/specific-function/isolated-voltage-current-detector/acpl-k370-000e).

Following the [application note 1004](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-3699EN) example 1, I am able to successfully calculate the Rx value and simulate the model as shown below. The idea here was to have a circuit that can detect DC from 12-48V. When the input voltage is below the cutoff, the Vo = 5v and when there is presence of voltage between 12-48, it will show close to zero as per the truth table. So all works as expected on the DC side.

[image]

However, I am not able to simulate the same for AC input using example 3, AC operation with input filtering. Below is the circuit that I am trying to simulate.

[image]

The main issue is whether the input voltage is in the detection range or not, Vo always outputs 5v. Here the Rx= 17.8 kohms value is calculated using V- of 81.5VAC and using Eq.16 and Rp = 1.2k using Eq.17.

Any idea or suggestion what am I doing wrong or is missing in the circuit?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the input amplitude little by little until you find where it starts to work (if it does at all)?  You can also do a parameter sweep to make that process more automatic.

Comment: Yes, I did try but so far no luck. :(

Comment: Really?  I duplicated your circuit and the output starts switching if I set the sine wave peak to 129V.  Anything below that doesn't work.  The takeaway is that when the input is 129V the peak voltage at the AC1 pin reaches 4.97V.  When I briefly skimmed the app note, I recall that the threshold voltage is 5.1V.  I think you're problem has something to do with this.

Comment: I think then that might be the problem I am seeing. I will try to use the values you mentioned to see how the simulation behaves. Thank You for looking into this!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ste Kulov for some of the pointers. Following your suggestions, these are some of the results I am getting and the modifications that I have made to the simulation.

Setting the input sine wave peak to 129VAC started switching the Vo as shown below.
[image]

For the Vo to be detected as a logic HIGH when the V- is below 129VAC or LOW for above, I have now enabled the output filtering using CL = 27uF. This prevents the microcontroller from getting insane and continuously detecting high and low when the AC input switches between peak-to-peak.

[image]

which follows the similar trend shown in the datasheet:
[image]

Hopefully others will find this helpful. Any comments and feedback are always welcome.